# What device does the cmd command 'dir' use?

Tags: c, windows, device-driver, dir, rootkit

Sorry for the unclear question!

The command prompt command 'dir' lists all files and directories in a directory, as you probably know.

I am reading *"Subverting the Windows Kernel: Rootkits"* at the moment.

One example of code in the book hides TCP connections. It uses hooking. Part of the method it uses gets a pointer to **TCPIP.sys**, the driver that **'netstat'** uses to query the current TCP connections, by using the device object associated with it.

Basically there is a function, `IoGetDeviceObjectPointer()`, that takes a device name (for TCPIP.sys, the device was `\\DEVICE\\TCP`) and returns a pointer to the device driver, in that example TCPIP.sys.

I was wondering if anyone knows whether the '`dir`' command uses a device driver, and if so, what is the name of the device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, dir command not use device driver.
Dir commad relies on FindFirstFile/FindNextFile API functions, which calls Ntdll.dll kernel functions internally. If I remember correctly hookingNt/ ZwQueryInformationFile hides files.

Comment: That's technically true, but the same could be said of netstat as it doesn't talk directly to the tcp driver.  In the case of dir, eventually a request will be made to the file system driver.  Of course user mode hooking is much easier than kernel mode hooking.

Comment: That's technically true, but file system driver also talk with disk driver, so we may discuss about 'name of device'. :)